# Best way to replace DSL cable by CAT6 cable

Tags: layer1, cable, adsl

Best way to **replace DSL cable by CAT6 cable**, to decrease resistances and improve connection.

1. Use **1 pair** only.
2. Connect **every 2 pairs together**.
3. Connect **White wires together** and **Colored wires together**.

Note: Every **pair is twisted**.

[image]

Comment: Your standard Category-3 cable will work just fine for DSL, and you really are not gaining anything with Category-6 cable. The fact is that the DSL is being delivered from the CO to your site via Category-3. Also, the _ANSI/TIA/EIA 568, Commercial Building Telecommunications Cabling Standard_ says that you cannot build Category-6 patch cables and workstation cords. I have never seen a cable installer be able to build one and have it pass the Category-6 test suite. It has nothing to do with resistance, it is about frequency rating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DSL line runs for hundreds or even thousands of meters on plain telephone cable (Cat-3ish). A few meters of Cat-6 will change nothing to improve signal integrity.

Just use any pair. Don't interconnect pairs.

Note that your middle drawing will degrade the signal significantly due to not using the twisted pairs. The bottom drawing improves nothing but might increase echos and distortions substantially.